# How to resolve missing server problem in netbeans installed in Debian?

Tags: java, ide, netbeans, debian

I have installed netbeans in Debian and no server is listed in "Available java EE compatible servers" when trying to resolve. Also, cannot "Add server" by giving "platform folder location". By default, it appears "/home/raj/SUNWappserver". The error "provide valid application server location" not disappears whatever is typed in "platform location".

1. Which is the location?(for glassfish server and tomcat)
2. What option should be chosen for domain?( if i am trying to work with web services from 2 machines by creating one server and one client). I can't type anyuthing in "Domain" or "profile"
   3.While installing, is there any plug in to be included?
   Kindly help.

Comment: which version of NB did you install?

Answer (score 3):

Right click your project and next click resolve missing server.
Open dialog box so you will add server in current glash fish server next solve your problem.

Answer (score -1):

1. Go to File menu.
2. Click on Exit (Again Restart Your NetBeans). Auto Added Missing Server.

Comment: Hi, can you please elaborate on how the Missing Server will be "auto added" after restarting NetBeans? I tried restarting, but the issue is still there.